# how to merge $facet results base on _id field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I write aggregate Query via $facet like this:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            result1: result1AggQry,
            result2: result2AggQry
        }
    },
]);
```

hitherto the result is like this:

```
[
    {
        result1:[
            {_id:"1", feild_res1="v"},
            {_id:"2", feild_res1="w"},
        ]
    },
    {
        result2:[
            {_id:"1", feild_res2="x"},
            {_id:"2", feild_res2="y"},
            {_id:"3", feild_res2="z"},
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, for getting result as below, I want to add a stage to the Aggregation:

```
[
    {
        finalResult:[
            {_id:"1", feild_res1="v", feild_res2="x"},
            {_id:"2", feild_res1="w", feild_res2="y"},
            {_id:"3", feild_res2="z"},
        ]
    }
]
```

Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: share the query that you are using in $facet

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- `$project` with `$concatArrays` to combine the results arrays
- `$unwind` the combined results
- `$group` by the results _id field, using `$push` and `$objectToArray` to build an array containing arrays of key-value pairs
- `$project` with `$reduce`, using `$concatArrays` to combine the arrays into a single array, and `$arrayToObject` to convert the combined array to an object
- `$group` to collect the objects into the finalResults array